# How to improve tesseract.js accuracy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ocr, tesseract.js

Im using this piece of code from the website but its not accurate enough

```
 const worker1 = createWorker();
  const worker2 = createWorker();

  await worker1.load();
  await worker2.load();
  await worker1.loadLanguage("eng");
  await worker2.loadLanguage("eng");
  await worker1.initialize("eng");
  await worker2.initialize("eng");

  scheduler.addWorker(worker1);
  scheduler.addWorker(worker2);

  /** Add 10 recognition jobs */
  const {
    data: { text }
  } = await scheduler.addJob("recognize", image);
```

this is the type of image i'm trying to read its text:

[image]

thou it seems simple and easy ,sometimes tesseract fails to read it .
is there any better alternatives to tesseract.js or any way to improve the accuracy?

Comment: Have you tried applying some filtering on the input images, to enhance the contrast, for example or enlarge them? I think one way to get better accuracy, is to do some modifications on the input images.

Comment: actually i have applied some filters and removed some level of noise to make it more clear and performance is improved , but still its unable to read sometimes, i dont know why

Comment: you suggest any special modifications ?

Comment: You can start with this post: https://docparser.com/blog/improve-ocr-accuracy/
Increasing contrast, image sharpening, removing noise are some basic image enhancements that might help you get better accuracy results.

Comment: Additionally, you might want to check threshold filtering. See this code for example: https://github.com/laurenzcodes/Canvas-Threshold-Effect

Comment: You can also dive deeper into edge detection algorithms, like the Sobel Algorithm or Canny Algorithm.

Comment: I use a negative version of your image and it works fine. Also additional gamma correction looks promising.

Comment: I am facing accuracy issues as well piping in an HTML canvas with very basic black strokes on a white background. I am getting wildly inconsistent results with even just attempting to detect numbers :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applying OCR using Tesseract, it is important to preprocess the image so that the **desired text to detect is in black with the background in white**. To do this, you can apply a simple threshold to obtain a binary image. Here's the image after preprocessing:

[image]

Result from Tesseract

```
52024
```

I implemented this approach in Python OpenCV, but you can adapt a similar strategy into Javascript!

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Load image and Otsu's Threshold to get a binary image
image = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Perform OCR
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , do you know any special node js library to achieve that ?

Comment: using jimp i inverted the color and the accuracy is really improved and i think its enough for my current project , but i still need some good library to do that in  node js , anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with node.js but once you find one you can follow the same approach. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding Jimp; I'm not sure why it shouldn't be possible to port it but I found something that looks similar and runs on Node.js: [Nimp](https://github.com/dan335/nimp)

Comment: I can recommend using the `sharp` npm library, it has all these features built in